# Rails: Destroy session with a session_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a gem which needs to destroy arbitrary session by a session_id.

Currently I'm using the following codes

```
case Rails.application.config.session_store
when ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore
  Rails.cache.delete("_session_id:#{session_id}")
when ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
  ActiveRecord::SessionStore.session_class.find(session_id).destroy
when ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
  # cannot remove a client-storage session
end
```

But I've found `destroy_session(env, session_id, options)` method for every `SessionStorage` class. How can I call this method in a script? (not in a request or any controller)

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing session in the DB, can you try this in your console:

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

You can also destroy the whole session with the following from your controller:

```
reset_session
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I'm currently write a gem which need to destroy arbitrary session by a session_id. So I want to call some methods like `ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore#destroy_session`. But I don't know how to call it.